# fancytree css style for selected/expanded icon

Tags: css, fancytree

I'm creating a tree to select a folder for a file destination so it only supports single selection. The expanders are hidden and I have + or - on the folder icons. Clicking on the folder icon with will expand or collapse the tree. The folder icon as well as the title changes (color) to indicate which folder is selected.

I used custom icons because i had different types of folders.

It works for collapsed selected or collapsed unselected. It works for expanded selected, but I can't get the stylesheet to work for a selected, expanded folder.

The following displays the expanded folder icon with a - sign when unselected

```
span.fancytree-expanded > span.fancytree-custom-icon.FolderWithChildren {
    background-image: url("FolderMinus.png");
}
```

However I can't figure out the syntax for a selected/expanded folder. I've tried many variation but nothing works. For example;

```
span.fancytree-expanded > span.fancytree-selected span.fancytree-custom-icon.FolderWithChildren {
    background-image: url("FolderMinusSelected.png");
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to use something that already exists?

Comment: This already exists, I'm just trying to change the style for an updated design.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
span.fancytree-expanded.fancytree-selected > span.fancytree-custom-icon.FolderWithChildren {
    background-image: url("FolderMinusSelected.png");
}
```